# Bootstrap Dropdown submenu is not showing in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dropdown and it contains submenu. But the submenu is not showing. My code is given below.  If there is any mistake please let me know.

```
<div class="dropdown ">

    <span class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu  pull-right ">
        <li class="dropdown-item ">Books</li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
               Games</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-repeat="game in games">
                <li class="dropdown-item " ng-click="getGames()">
                    {{game.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

A dropdown contains two menu item which is Books and Games. After select games it should display list of game names from backend and it is not showing.  Actually I can get the game names without using bootstrap dropdown menu. Any I am not giving the proper code. I need the suggession for dropdown submenu only. so that I gave that part of code only.

Comment: Are you getting value in `games` variable of `ng-repeat` ? Share a plunkr to get quick solution

Answer (score 0):

you should need to put ng-repeat inside li and not ul.

change this code:

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-repeat="game in games">
            <li class="dropdown-item " ng-click="getGames()">
                {{game.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

to this code:

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li class="dropdown-item " ng-click="getGames()" ng-repeat="game in games">
                {{game.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: can you please add your code (controller, html), or if you can add it to plunker (https://plnkr.co/), that will be great.